# How can ı send 3 data in onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

I tried every way but ı can't send 3 data with onclick event

How can use onclick with multi data,

I am new in programming

MY error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

```
          var customerTable = $('#phoneList tbody');
              customerTable.empty();
                  for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                      customerTable.append('<tr>' +
                          '<td>' + msg[i].PhoneNo + '</td>' +
                          '<td>' + msg[i].PhoneID + '</td>' +
                          '<td class="text-right">' + "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-circle' onclick='PhoneCreate("+msg[i].Ref+msg[i].PhoneNo+msg[i].PhoneID +" )'  type='button'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button>" +
                          "<button class='btn btn-warning btn-circle' onclick='PhoneDelete(" + msg[i].Ref + ")' type='button'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button>" +
                          '</tr>');
                  }
```

Comment: Try to wrap the arguments in quotes, eg: `..PhoneDelete('" + msg[i].Ref + "')..`. You should use `document.createElement(..)` or, at least, string templates.

Answer (score 1):

While it would be technically possible to fix your existing code by escaping the characters in the string, it would be much better (and much easier to manage) if you attached the listener using Javascript instead - that way, you don't have to worry about escaping issues, and you don't have to pollute the global scope for the listeners to work:

```
var customerTable = $('#phoneList tbody');
customerTable.empty();
for (const { Ref, PhoneNo, PhoneID } of msg) {
 const $tr = $(`
   <tr>
     <td>${PhoneNo}</td>
     <td>${PhoneID}</td>
     <td class="text-right">
       <button class='btn btn-primary btn-circle' type='button'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button>
       <button class='btn btn-warning btn-circle' type='button'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button>
     </td>
   </tr>
 `);
 $tr.find('.fa-edit').on('click', () => PhoneCreate(Ref, PhoneNo, PhoneID));
 $tr.find('.fa-trash').on('click', () => PhoneDelete(Ref));
 customerTable.append($tr);
}
```

(make sure to properly end the `<td>` - for the final cell, it's missing in the original code)